# 7zip: In C#, how to add multiple files of the same name in different directories to the same zip file?

Tags: 7zip

I created a C# snippet that calls 7zip (7za) to add a list of files to a zip archive.  Problem is multiple files in different directories have the same name, so 7zip either complains about duplicate names or replaces the first file with the second only storing the last added.  I cannot recursively scan a directory which would allow duplicates.

Is there a way to force 7zip to store the directory, or in ASP.NET MVC 3 C# to create zip files with duplicate file names when not considering the full path?

The path to our image is the GTIN number broken up by every five digits.  The last five are the name of the image.

```
 G:\1234\56789\01234.jpg
 G:\4321\09876\01234.jpg
 G:\5531\33355\01234.jpg
```

These would fail to all store in a 7zip archive correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SevenZipSharp: http://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/ a wrapper around 7zip. You will have full control from code.

Comment: https://github.com/squid-box/SevenZipSharp new location

Answer (score 0):

We managed to get multiples in the same archive by creating a file list that doesn't contain leading backslashes, then running the application from the directory containing them:

```
1234\56789\01234.jpg
4321\09876\01234.jpg
5531\33355\01234.jpg
```

It solves it for now.  Anyone with a better idea?